# How can I route to an element in CakePHP?

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.3, url-routing

Is it accepted (and possible) to route to an element in CakePHP? I have a sidebar which I'm loading content into dynamically through some ajax tabs, but upon initial pageload, I don't want to have to call the first tab through ajax, I'd just like to display the element itself with PHP.

I figured by moving it into an element, I can load just the content I want, and not the rest of the view elements.

Is this an ok practice? I figure that there may be some issues with Google trying to index the specific element, which would just show the content, and no view, so I guess I'd have to restrict that for this specific element as well.

Comment: Why element and not an action?

Comment: @powtac I wanted to take advantage of the caching abilities with elements that you can do with CakePHP. Not sure if I could replicate that as easily with an action.

Comment: If you want to point trough an URL to a specific piece of content you have to do it by an action, but you could do it with an /showelement/123 action to shown an specific element.

Answer (score 1):

Routing element is not the good way.
You have to create new action and call the your element their. doing this you can still you the caching of cakePHP.